# JWT implementation in Java using .pem file

Tags: java, jwt

Would like to know if JWT implementation (generating token) in Java is only possible only via .jks file in keystore of we can do it using a .pem (certificate and key) file as well ?

I would like to store the .jks file in a secured location offered by the PaaS provider on which my application is running and this service does not allow a physical file to be stored but rather the encoded format of the binary contents can be stored in key value pair which we have to refer by decoding. However when i do so , I get a Invalid keystore error.Hence i would like to know if .jks is a mandate for JWT token generation ?

Comment: No, .jks is not mandatory for the JWT token generation. Please add code snippet where you're using the keystore file

Comment: KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");

Comment: //Steps to form the private key from Keystore certificate 
 KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
 keystore.load(new FileInputStream(file), jwtstorePassword.toCharArray());
 PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(jwtstoreAlias, jwtstorePassword.toCharArray());
 
 // Steps to form the certificate used in the above step as "file"
  tmpFileCert = File.createTempFile("certfilejwt", ".jks");
 fileWriter = new FileWriter(tmpFileCert);
 String base64String = jwtValue;
 byte[] bytedecryptMessage =  java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);

Comment: String decodedString = new String(bytedecryptMessage);
 fileWriter.write(decodedString);
 
 The jwtValue here is the encoded version of the .jks file [base64 -w 0 certfile.jks] stored in secure repo in the PaaS provider.

Answer (score 3):

As per your requirement, you don't want to use the `Keystore` & instead of that you directly wants to read the private & public keys (or public certificate), you can easily achieve it by the following. I've added the apache codec library dependency `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;` for the Base64 decoding purpose.

```
public static RSAPrivateKey readPrivateKey(File file) throws Exception {
    String key = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), Charset.defaultCharset());

    String privateKeyPEM = key.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
        .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "").replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

    byte[] encoded = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyPEM);

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
    return (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
  }

// to call above code
// private.key in PEM format
File file = new File("private.key");
PrivateKey key = readPrivateKey(file);
```

Similar things can be done for reading the public key and public certificate as per the requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for immediate response.I tried the same and now I get the following error. Will check the same. "java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=40, too big."

Comment: @dev2021 did you find solution for above exception. "java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=40, too big."

Comment: Not yet @Mihir...